# strange yellow (!) line next to html element

Tags: html, css, layout

I get this **strange yellow (!) line** between the `#mainContainer` and the `HTML-body`, only on the right side though and only below the `header/nav-section`.

Happens in **Chrome** and **Firefox**.

**EDIT:**
I got rid of the yellow line after playing around with it for ages. Not sure WHY, but it is gone now. I've put the code here in case someone has a similar problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>navbar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="mainContainer">

        <header>
            <h1>Test Webseite</h1>
        </header>

        <nav>
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">test2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">test3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">test4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">test5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <section>
            Lorem ipsum 
        </section>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    height:100%;
    }
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #dedede;
    width:700px;
    height: 100%;
    }
#mainContainer {

    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    }

header {
    background: #00795f;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 40px 0;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
nav ul {
    background: #424242;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}

nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #399077;
}
ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 12px 35px;
}
section {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    padding: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: inter-word;

}
```

Comment: I don't see it. Does it happen after a click or something ?

Comment: I see the yellow line and i've done a bit of digging to find out it's a part of the body margin. Setting the margin to not be auto does one side! that's close enough right?

Comment: simply put just mess with the body margin a bit. See if you can more than I have.

Comment: exclamation mark: this line is a surprise to me.... and why is it yellow of all colors? There's no yellow on the entire page. Hence the exclamation mark :)

Comment: background-color: #ddddaa; that is the colour you have set the background to be you just gotta sort the margin out. or maybe it's padding! who knows

Comment: come back and see if my answer is what you wanted! lol

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #ddddaa;
}

header {
  background: #00795f;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px 0;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#mainContainer {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #D2D2D2;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px 35px;
}

nav ul {
  background: #424242;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: #399077;
}

section {
  line-height: 1.7em;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
  background-color: #ffffff
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>navbar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <h1>Test Webseite</h1>
  </header>
  <div id="mainContainer">
    <nav>
      <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <section>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime soluta incidunt ipsam, asperiores consequatur esse. Optio velit animi molestiae autem quas dignissimos architecto, blanditiis repellat rem nobis et adipisci perspiciatis quidem laudantium
      eaque corporis minima eos neque sapiente provident! Est, quod. Voluptates nisi hic vero deleniti neque veritatis facilis, nesciunt officiis? Laudantium vero autem, aspernatur consequatur! Ad assumenda, neque excepturi aut asperiores voluptatibus!
      Magni, saepe! Nisi laboriosam ea illo doloribus fugiat minus maiores! Magnam voluptatibus, deserunt aspernatur. Aperiam natus voluptatum libero magni? Tenetur quae optio, perferendis enim nesciunt quam inventore dolor necessitatibus, alias asperiores
      dolore. Hic perspiciatis quia laborum. Maxime porro eaque vero, laudantium blanditiis odio quam qui eius nulla consequatur doloremque quos optio minima recusandae laboriosam consectetur! Deserunt at expedita libero, alias quasi tempora dolores,
      doloremque illo eveniet aperiam facere totam molestias, eaque nihil odio consequatur esse. Ut eius facere vitae molestias optio, esse tenetur exercitationem facilis beatae, maiores nam! Dignissimos nulla ipsum a iure numquam ducimus aut ea nemo
      nihil, odit possimus magni dolor hic reiciendis exercitationem, error nesciunt dolorum eius, odio obcaecati consectetur repudiandae sapiente repellat omnis sunt! Quas ducimus at, nam laudantium. Architecto quas facere perferendis pariatur esse natus
      eligendi enim, doloremque nesciunt nulla. Vel, quasi.
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I've been frantically prickling at this and I believe it was the width properties. This works and DOESN'T have any margin! Run the snippet see if it's what you wanted! Removed width, max-width and padding.

edit: if you want the entire white space there yellow then you're targeting the wrong element... your main container shows a white background just change that if thats what you want

edit2: I've edited it again to (hopefully) suit what you wanted...

Comment: thanks for your help! I want a grey background and a big main white container. If I put the "max-width: 850px;" back to the body, the line is there again...

Comment: What part do you want grey exactly? Is it the header or the main container where the text is??

Comment: Like on many websites, I'd like the text area (lorem ipsum....) to be white, and the main (i.e. body) background colour to be a light grey... THANKS again!

Comment: i've done another edit... dunno if it's what you want though lol

Comment: sorry, it got kind of confusing :) Basically I want the layout to be like in the very first post, just WITHOUT the annoying yellow line...

Comment: i'm not gonna tinker with this anymore I believe you can simply expand on what i've done and try and bash your way through it. good luck lol

Answer (score 0):

I have changed some colors now. Now the yellow line next to white area is gone.
But **instead there is a blue line** on the right hand side of the green header area (if you look closely) !

Someone pointed out, it could be an optical illusion. Could they be right? I find that somewhat hard to believe. And why is it just on the right side and not on the left ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>navbar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">    
</head>
<body>
<div id="mainContainer">
    <header>
        <h1>Test Webseite</h1>
    </header>

    <nav>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">test2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">test3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">test4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">test5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <section>
            Lorem ipsum 
    </section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;    
    background-color: grey;
}
header{
    background: green;
    width:100%;
    padding: 40px 0;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
#mainContainer {
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 850px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 12px 35px;
}
nav ul{
    background: #424242;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:0;
}
nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size:16px;
}
nav ul li:hover{
    background-color: #399077;
}
section{
    line-height: 1.7em;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    padding: 40px;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: inter-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it now and edited the very first post!